# Pinescript - for loop with input variable

Tags: loops, pine-script

i use tradingview with pinescript 4. I want to insert information on tickers i use (time, buy, sold). When i select a ticker, the script must make a loop to verify if there is variable for this ticker. If the the test is ok, i want to use this variable (buy1 or buy2, sold1 or sold2) on my script by replacing "BuyAlertLevel" and "SellAlertLevel" to draw line.

The problem is "line 41: Undeclared identifier 'buy'; line 42: Undeclared identifier 'sold'"

```
RSIPeriod = input(41, minval=1)
BuyAlertLevel = input(5, step=1, title="Buy Alert")
SellAlertLevel = input(15, step=1, title="Sell Alert")
RSIHistoModify = input(1.5, step=0.1, title="RSI Modify")

tickers1 = input(title="S", type=input.string, defval="PUST", group = "Suivi des Valeurs", inline = "1")
time1 =input(title="T", type=input.integer, defval=120, group = "Suivi des Valeurs", inline = "1")
buy1 =input(defval=0, title="B", type=input.integer,  group = "Suivi des Valeurs", inline = "1")
sold1 =input(title="S", type=input.integer, defval=15, group = "Suivi des Valeurs", inline = "1")

tickers2 = input(title="S", type=input.string, defval="PANX", group = "Suivi des Valeurs", inline = "2")
time2 =input(title="T", type=input.integer, defval=120, group = "Suivi des Valeurs", inline = "2")
buy2 =input(title="B", type=input.integer, defval=0,  group = "Suivi des Valeurs", inline = "2")
sold2 =input(title="S", type=input.integer, defval=15, group = "Suivi des Valeurs", inline = "2")

var tickers = (syminfo.ticker)

for int i = 1 to 2
    if (tickers == tickers[i] and timeframe.multiplier == time[i])
        BuyAlertLevel := buy[i]
        SellAlertLevel := sold[i]

hline(0, "hline" ,color=color.purple, linestyle=hline.style_solid)
plot(BuyAlertLevel, color=color.green, style=plot.style_line)
plot(SellAlertLevel, color=color.red, style=plot.style_line)
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This uses the levels from one of the two symbols when the chart's symbol matches it, otherwise it uses the input values for the levels:

```
//@version=4
study("")
RSIPeriod = input(41, minval=1)
i_BuyAlertLevel = input(5, step=1, title="Buy Alert")
i_SellAlertLevel = input(15, step=1, title="Sell Alert")
RSIHistoModify = input(1.5, step=0.1, title="RSI Modify")

tickers1 = input(title="S", type=input.string, defval="PUST", group = "Suivi des Valeurs", inline = "1")
time1 =input(title="T", type=input.integer, defval=120, group = "Suivi des Valeurs", inline = "1")
buy1 =input(defval=0, title="B", type=input.integer,  group = "Suivi des Valeurs", inline = "1")
sold1 =input(title="S", type=input.integer, defval=15, group = "Suivi des Valeurs", inline = "1")

tickers2 = input(title="S", type=input.string, defval="PANX", group = "Suivi des Valeurs", inline = "2")
time2 =input(title="T", type=input.integer, defval=120, group = "Suivi des Valeurs", inline = "2")
buy2 =input(title="B", type=input.integer, defval=0,  group = "Suivi des Valeurs", inline = "2")
sold2 =input(title="S", type=input.integer, defval=15, group = "Suivi des Valeurs", inline = "2")

var float BuyAlertLevel  = syminfo.ticker == tickers1 ? buy1  : syminfo.ticker == tickers2 ? buy2  : i_BuyAlertLevel
var float SellAlertLevel = syminfo.ticker == tickers1 ? sold1 : syminfo.ticker == tickers2 ? sold2 : i_SellAlertLevel

hline(0, "hline" ,color=color.purple, linestyle=hline.style_solid)
plot(BuyAlertLevel, color=color.green, style=plot.style_line)
plot(SellAlertLevel, color=color.red, style=plot.style_line)

plot(close)
```

You were confusing the [history-referencing operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator) with how arrays are often indexed in other languages. See the usrman [here for information on arrays in Pine](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Arrays.html).